# Problema con el método setInterval JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, variables, setinterval

estoy intentando seleccionar unos divs que va creando un bucle (creado con un setTimeout dentro de otro setTimeout), y para ello estoy usando un setInterval a parte. Lo raro es que dentro de ese setInterval me dice que lo que intento seleccionar es NULL, pensé que era porque el setInterval no era capaz de recoger la variable contador que se se suma en 1 en el bucle para ir cambiado las ID de cada div que crea. Pero he puesto un console.log con esa variable, y si la lee, pero no el selector. Espero que el codigo no sea muy lioso y me podáis ayudar. Un saludo y gracias!!

PD: Lo que intento hacer es un generador de pequeños divs con anchos y altos aleatorios que vayan saliendo desde abajo y suban con transition, pero en el setInterval en el que intentaba cambiarle mediante DOM su posición vertical, no me reconoce los divs cuando intento seleccionarlo.
PD2: La variable "partVertical" es la que me reconoce como null.

```
        var i = 1;
        function bucle() {

            var posicionParticula = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 0);
            var anchoParticula = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 2 + 1) + 2);
            var altoParticula = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 2 + 1) + 2);

            var min = 1;
            var max = 4;
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            console.log('Wait for ' + rand + ' seconds');
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<div id="particula'+i+'" class="particula" style="width: '+anchoParticula+'px; height: '+altoParticula+'px; background: skyblue; position: absolute; left: '+posicionParticula+'%; top: 100%; transition: 5s;"></div>';
            i++;
            setTimeout(bucle, rand * 1000);
        }
        bucle();
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log(i);
        var partVertical = document.querySelector('#particula' +i).style.top;
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: partVertical es null porque la funcion console.log() no devuelve nada, es un void. Estas diciendo que partVertical es igual a lo que devuelve log, osea null

Comment: Quieres hacer un efecto de como si estuviera nevando en el monitor????

Comment: #Elfuturo Llego Cierto, ha sido un fallo de copia-pega y ya lo he editado jejeje, aún así no consigo evitar el error de: document.querySelector(...) is null, refiriendose al selector que se encuentra en la variable partVertical.

Comment: #Yussef sip, eso intento pero quiero que la nieve salga desde abajo de la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

yo veo 2 cosas:
1- Te falta cerrar las comillas dobles desp de id="particula

```
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<div id="particula'+i
```

2- Como bien dicen arriba, te conviene separar

```
var partVertical = document.querySelector("#particula")
console.log(partVertical)
```

Comentario aparte, deberias cambiar las var por let o const

Comment: Gracias por responder Carlos! pero donde indicas las comillas dobles si están cerradas en id="particula'+i+'" lo que pasa que alomejor tienes que hacer scroll a la derecha en la ventanita del codigo. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo!

Comment: no me entendiste creo, defines id:"particula" abriendo con comillas dobles antes de la palabra particula, por lo cual debes cerrar la busqueda del id con comillas dobles, podrias probar con template strings si no ves lo que te digo. Yo lo probe con esa modif y empece a ver que aparecian cuadritos aleatorios en la parte inferior de la pantalla

Comment: Buenas de nuevo Carlos. La linea que muestras en tu respuesta para mostrarme que "Falta cerrar con las comillas dobles" no está completa, tienes que hacer scroll a la derecha en el codigo que yo he publicado.

Te adjunto un trozo de linea aqui en el comentario a ver si puedes apreciarlo mejor desde aqui, un saludo!

document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<div id="particula'+i+'" class="particula" style="width: '+anchoParticula+'px; ...

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo he arreglado cambiando ese bucle formado por setTimeout por un while que se encarga de crear primero todos los divs. Despues con el mismo bucle que muestro arriba (Un setTimeout dentro de otro setTimeout) voy moviendo uno por uno los divs hacia arriba con: top: -'+alturaParticula+'; Funciona muy bien, espero que le sirva a alguien! Gracias a todos!

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).